# SwiftUI weird behaviour when using `safeAreaInset` modifier in `NavigationStack`

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trying to make header pinned between below the navigation bar using `safeAreaInset` modifier. When I start swiping navigation bar down, the `safeAreaInset` content remains on the same position although navigation title and `List` content moves down.

Is it possible to make the header scrolling along with the navigation bar?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      List([0, 1, 2, 3], id: \.self) {
        Text("\($0)")
      }
      .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
      .safeAreaInset(edge: .top, alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Safe Area Header")
          .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
          .font(.title)
          .padding()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found the out of the box SwiftUI solution. But I was able to fix this by observing the `List` offset and then calculating the correct header inset (`firstRowInset - safeAreaTopInset`).

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State private var scrollOffset = 0.0
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      ItemsList(items: [0, 1, 2, 3])
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .top, alignment: .leading) {
          Text("Safe Area Header")
            .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
            .font(.title)
            .padding()
            .offset(y: max(scrollOffset, 0.0))
        }
        .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
        .onPreferenceChange(
          ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self,
          perform: { scrollOffset = $0 }
        )
    }
  }
  
  private struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(
      value: inout CGFloat,
      nextValue: () -> CGFloat
    ) {
      value += nextValue()
    }
  }
  
  private struct ItemsList: View {
    let items: [Int]
    
    var body: some View {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
          Row(value: item)
            .background {
              if item == items.first {
                ScrollOffsetPreferenceView(
                  safeAreaInsets: geometry.safeAreaInsets
                )
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private struct Row: View {
    let value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
      Text("\(value)")
        .frame(
          maxWidth: .infinity,
          maxHeight: .infinity,
          alignment: .leading
        )
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .padding()
    }
  }
  
  private struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceView: View {
    let safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets
    
    var body: some View {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear
          .preference(
            key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self,
            value: offset(geometry: geometry)
          )
      }
    }
    
    private func offset(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
      let safeAreaTopInset = safeAreaInsets.top
      let rowOffset = geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.y
      return rowOffset - safeAreaTopInset
    }
  }
}
```